# Как я могу сделать div с irregular shapes с помощью css3 и html5?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Мне интересно, есть ли возможность построить `div` с нерегулярными фигурами, что-то,аналогичные картам (например, Гренландия, Европа, Африка)

Я хочу создать карту, как здесь, используя `CSS3` и `HTML5`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/12126731/7394871

Answer (score 3):

То, что у вас на картинке, похоже на `grid`(сетку), которую вы можете получить либо со многими градиентами на `div`, либо с сеткой из многих `div`, на которые вы применяете `CSS-transforms` ([DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/3475567)).

Вот ключевой момент в правилах `CSS`, которые отвечают за трансформацию всего набора квадратов и придания ему 3D эффекта:

```
.grid {
    transform: skewX(-45deg) 
        rotate(15deg) 
        scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8)
        translateX(-4.5em) translateY(-3em);
}
```

Ниже неполный код, показывающий, как реализована структура приложения:

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='grid'>
        <div class='grid-row'>
            <div class='grid-cell'></div>
            <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

CSS:

```
div { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 32em;
    height: 32em;
    margin: 5.6em auto 0;
    background: silver;
}
.grid {
    transform: skewX(-45deg) 
        rotate(15deg) 
        scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8)
        translateX(-4.5em) translateY(-3em);
}
.grid-row {
    width: 32em;
    height: 2em;
}
.grid-cell {
    float: left;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
}
.high {
    background: gainsboro;
}
.high:hover {
    background: whitesmoke;
}
```

**Полный код**

```css
div { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 32em;
 height: 32em;
 margin: 5.6em auto 0;
 background: silver;
}
.grid {
 transform: skewX(-45deg) 
  rotate(15deg) 
  scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8)
  translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
}
.grid-row {
 width: 32em;
}
.grid-cell {
 float: left;
 width: 2em;
 height: 2em;
}
.high {
 box-shadow: .2em .2em 0 dimgrey;
 background: gainsboro;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.high:hover {
 background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<!-- content to be placed inside <body>…</body> -->
<div class='container'>
 <div class='grid'>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-row'>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
   <div class='grid-cell high'></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128398/7394871)